# How to put Youku video on my wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, youku

I already tried various plugin, none of those works...please help, thanks

The code that able to display Youtube video is this: (replacing the youtube link with youku is not working obviously)

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/4"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_video link="https://youtu.be/CC0oCjTJAMg"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/4"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][vc_row_inner css=".vc_custom_1529069482532{margin-top: 20px !important;border-top-width: 20px !important;padding-top: 20px !important;}"][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_single_image image="19894" img_size="full" css_animation="left-to-right"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_column_text css_animation="right-to-left"]

Comment: This isn't a code question, and therefore isn't appropriate for SO. Shortcode is proprietary based on the plugins you're using. Does Youku provide simple embed code you can drop into Text View?

Comment: yes, the share button in Youku give me 3 codes:

Comment: 1. <iframe height=498 width=510 src='http://player.youku.com/embed/XMzg4NTExMzUzMg==' frameborder=0 'allowfullscreen'></iframe>

Comment: 2. <embed src='http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzg4NTExMzUzMg==/v.swf' allowFullScreen='true' quality='high' width='480' height='400' align='middle' allowScriptAccess='always' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'></embed>

Comment: 3. http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzg4NTExMzUzMg==/v.swf

Comment: The last one isn't embed markup--it's just a URL. The first two should work in Text View unless WP strips those tags for security. I'd use the iframe version for more modern behavior.

Comment: can i know how to use the code (either one) to make it works, what do you mean by Text View?

Comment: Your editor has two modes: Visual and Text. The latter is raw markup.

Comment: oh yes, so I just need to copy the code then put inside 'Text'?

Comment: I just tried both, both give the same result, the page not showing any video but leave a black space there :(

Comment: I see from the link Noraldaim Linux posted that iframes will get stripped. You might try his/her solution.

Answer (score -2):

First, you wanna copy the html code from youku’s share function:

```html
<embed src="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XNDYwMTEzMTY0/v.swf" allowFullScreen="true" quality="high" width="480" height="400" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
```

Then, take the url and convert to the following:

```html
[gigya src="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XNDYwMTEzMTY0/v.swf" allowFullScreen="true" quality="high" width="480" height="400" allowScriptAccess="always" ]
```

You can change the width and height as well as the other attributes

Comment: What is `gigya`? Does it require a plugin? You might revise to make that more clear and link to any relevant resources.

Comment: source info https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/embed-video-from-youku/

Comment: And that link doesn't explain what `gigya` is.

Comment: i found this on google jus now before i seek for help in stackoverflow haha, i dun understand how to convert the sharing code from youku to gigya, there's no tool or link i can use to do that

Comment: when i paste this gigya code to the 'Text' there, the webpage just display the whole gigya original sentence, cuz is not using html tags lol

Comment: The Gigya Plugin for WordPress allows you to integrate Gigya's customer identity management platform throughout your WordPress site. With the Gigya plugin, you can easily build and maintain secure and scalable registration, authentication, profile management, data analytics and third-party integrations. Increase registrations and identify customers across devices, consolidate data into rich customer profiles, and provide better service, products and experiences by integrating data into marketing and service applications

Comment: i search gigya plugin, no such thing, or it's need to be paid?